# remote debugging linux machine intellij

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

i really need help.
i cant really figure out how to use the remote bugging. i am try to write a simple code that reads a file from my linux machine.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        linkedList listing = new linkedList();
        System.out.println("hi");
        String localMachine = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        System.out.println(localMachine);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/var/log/tradertools/omer/hi"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            String everything = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

i have used the right host ip in the configuration.. but how do i know what port i need to use?

i am getting Unable to open debugger port error.. please help

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug an app remotely, it must be started with remote debugging on.

When creating remote debug configuration in Intellij IDEA, in "Configuration > Command line arguments for running remote JVM" it provides hints how to do this. 
By default, the stated arguments are:

> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

This means that first you have to run your application with these parameters, and then it could be debugged on port 5005 (of course you can change it with any port you desire).

See more details here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html